# How to memoize a recursive function in c++ with precision

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program to find the Lucas Number using a recurrence relation. I used a map to store the values but when I run the program it'll output the correct values for the input up to an input of 45 roughly. For example 60 returns 18446744073418719042 when the solution for 60 is 3461452808002 After that the output is incorrect. I'm not sure where my precision starts to fail.

```
 #include <map>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long int lucasNumber( unsigned long long int n ){

    static std::map<unsigned long long int,unsigned long long int> values;

    if(n == 0) {
        return 2;
    } else if(n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    std::map<unsigned long long int,unsigned long long int>::iterator iter = values.find(n);

    if(iter == values.end()) {
        return values[n] = lucasNumber(n-1) + lucasNumber(n-2);
    } else {
        return iter->second;
    }
```

Here is the Main function class. Hopefully this will help clarify anything

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "csce310homeWork04part01.hpp"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc , char* argv[] ){
    unsigned long long int n;
    cin >> n;
    try{
        fprintf( stdout , "Lucas number %llu has a value of %llu\n" , n , lucasNumber( n ) );
    }
    catch( exception e ){
        cerr << "ERROR" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a bug. It is missing main()....Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: there is a main function its just in a different class

Comment: how is the output wrong? integers have no precision, they are exact. (there is no output in the code you show btw)

Comment: I ran this on my local machine and output seems fine
Lucas Number for 44 = 1568397607
Lucas Number for 45 = 2537720636
Lucas Number for 46 = 4106118243

Comment: there is nothing wrong in the code you show. Please read about [mcve] and try to provide one. We dont know what output you are looking at or why you think it is wrong. Please include output and expected output in the question along with a mcve

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: I'm seeing `45: 2537720636, 46: 4106118243` output, for the `main` I added.  What output are you getting?  Is that the output you expected?

Comment: it must be slightly higher than that because I have some test cases that involve numbers in the 60's and up and it isn't outputting correctly

Comment: Using my power of omniscience, the bug is in the code not shown.

Comment: what test cases produce incorrect result?

Comment: maybe it isnt "outputting correctly" because there is no output in your code?? we cannot know unless you let us see your code ;)

Comment: I added an example of how my output is wrong in the original post

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3GhftrGIoGfxveWX). Please do show us your `main` also. The problem is in code we dont know!

Comment: how do you print the value?

Comment: hum... I dont know c output. If you use c++ streams (`std::cout`) you'll get the right number

Comment: I am debugging it, now that you have a complete listing... will answer if I find a problem

Comment: Not reproducible https://ideone.com/LszpzL

Answer (score 0):

The following listing works fine for me. I only made very small edits so that I could debug it. Examine how I output the entire calculated sequence to file, so we can see where things went wrong, if they went wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef std::map<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> StorageType;
StorageType g_previouslyCalculatedValues{ {0, 2}, {1, 1} };

// Calculate Lucas Numbers up to the index specified
unsigned long long LucasNumber(unsigned long long n)
{
    StorageType::iterator iter = g_previouslyCalculatedValues.find(n);

    if (iter == g_previouslyCalculatedValues.end()) {
        return g_previouslyCalculatedValues[n] = LucasNumber(n - 1) + LucasNumber(n - 2);
    }

    return iter->second;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned long long int n;
    cout << "Enter the index of Lucas numbers to calculate" << endl;

    if ((cin >> n).fail())
    {
        cout << "Use an unsigned integer next time. Exiting..." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    try
    {
        StorageType::value_type result = LucasNumber(n);

        // Debug
        ofstream myfile("results.txt");
        for (auto element : g_previouslyCalculatedValues)
        {
            myfile << element.first << "\t: " << element.second << endl;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    catch (exception e)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR" << endl;
    }
}
```

I made the storage global rather than static,but tried it both ways and it worked fine. In the real world, it would be a class member in a calculator class. Are you sure you are testing the listing you gave us? It appears fine to me, using VS2017 64 bit!

```
Expected result: 3461452808002
Actual result: 3461452808002

From command line:
Enter the index of Lucas numbers to calculate
60
The lucas number for 60 is 3461452808002
```